# GeoMesa\GeoSpark - Points in polygons at different points in time

Tags: geospatial, temporal, geomesa

I am new to the geospatial temporal analytics on the spatial data. I have been exploring GeoSpark and GeoMesa but not getting closer to the problem described below.

> **Problem Statement**
>
> 1. Find all points within a given polygon or a set of polygons
> 2. Find if the majority of the points (say 50%) determined in the above is also found in some other polygons\areas\geo fence at different points in
>      time. UPDATE: It could be in some other given set of polygons or any other place (points within a certain distance to each other) within US region.

The data volume is in the order of Terrabytes.

Answer (score 1):

If you can express your geo-fence/time constraints as CQL predicates, then you could execute one query to get the count of points for 1), then execute a second query with an AND of your geo-fence/time constraints with the predicate from 1, and then compare the counts to determine if you have a majority or not.

Otherwise you could map each feature in your first query and manually evaluate the analytic against each one.

Comment: Thanks. In the second query, i do not have the list of polygons to query against. The majority of the points from the first query can be anywhere in the US region. It could be within given polygons or could be anywhere (lets say majority of the points within certain distance to each other). Updated the question.

Comment: Could you provide a concrete example of a query you want to evaluate? Thanks,